# Webview check for connectivity through out session

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a WebView app, and need to check for an Internet connection with every action "click" inside the app.  I got the following code working to check the internet on start up of the app.  But I need to figure out how to have this check every time the user changes pages with in the webview.

My code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if(!isNetworkConnectionAvailable()){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Sorry you need an Internet connection!  Please try again when the network" +
                " is available.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        finish();
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppViewClient());
}
```

And this is my connection checking code:

```
    public boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable() { 
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){ 
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    } 

}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can detect a new URL loaded request this way:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I learned to override that function so that clicking on a link in a webview does not open a new activity.  That function is called each time a user clicks on a URL.  I think you may be able to hook your connection check logic there.

I am curious though as to why you need to check this.  The webview control will show an error if there is no connection.  Are you just trying to short-circuit that error message?  There could be a very small timing window where your check succeeds, but then the website becomes unavailable when the click is processed.

Hope this helps,
Kevin

Comment: Kev, thanks I'll look into adding my logic in there.  As for why - I don't want users to see the "page not available" page with the web apps URL.